# Lan party network usage statistics

Tags: networking, dhcp, lan

Me and couple of my friends have decided to make a lan party around 40 to 50 players. I have couple of conserns I need to find solutions for.

1. DHCP server

   - I have now installed a DHCP server (in Virtual Box Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) and it worked. Here's how I did it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Vc6-0smd64
2. Bandwidth management

   - Possibly with the DHCP server, can I get some sort of statistics of the network such as current bandwidth usage per device. I'd be great to see network usage per device or in this case a player. That would make it a heck of a lot easier to track down bandwidth eaters aka "torrenting" since there is not a lot of bandwith to just give away.
   - I installed app called EtherApe to the DHCP server, selected eth0 as the Interface and it shows connections, but it would be very hard to track down a single pc out there, because EtherApe also lists the target. I'd like it to be like a list, possibly in ubuntu Terminal. For example:
   - ```
     user@hostname $ any command that outputs this
     | PC |     LAN      | Current usage | Total usage / |
     | -- | ------------ | ------------- | -------------- |
     | 1  | 192.168.1.20 |    4.687 Mbps |     1.256 Gbps |
     | 2  | 192.168.1.21 |    12.57 Mbps |    103.25 Mbps |
     | 3  | 192.168.1.23 |    0.245 Mbps |    12.144 Mbps |
     ```
3. Block connection

   - If player is using too much data all the time, having 20 tabs of Youtube playing 4K or torrenting a lot of files then block internet for that lan ip. This function should be used as manual because I could just kindly ask for the player to stop or I cut down the internet.
   - ```
     user@hostname $ blockinternet [lan ip] [interval]
     ```

Also if all of this could be done without proxy server then Ubuntu really rocks. Proxyless so players feel like home when they come. Plug and play. No proxy settings needed to be done. These features are not required to make a lan party but if someone starts to DDoS or torrent I would be great to have a tool to ban that PC for like 10 minutes (via SSH obviously ;)

I know this a lot to ask, but I have googled for couple days now still without a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of a way to manage this with just a ubuntu server installation but what i would recommend is using a managed cisco swtich. You can find powerful used cisco switches on ebay for as little $30 with 24 ports and configure your own security guidelines and remotely shut of ports if needed. For monitoring your network you can use software like [Solarwinds](http://www.solarwinds.com/) This kind of stuff can be overwhelming to get working and also not cost effective for your budget. Using a managed switch is the only way i see you getting the level of control you want.

Answer (score 0):

Managed switch will give you visibility of total traffic on your LAN per device.  Your local DHCP server can't see all the traffic (since that is what a switch does, only send the right traffic to the right port), so will never be able to do the job.

You won't find a 48 port Gigabit managed switch for $US30 though.

Since you're probably not worried about local LAN traffic bandwidth if you're all Gbit, you only need to manage the internet traffic.

There are lots of tools for that. The device will need two network ports or 2 vlans, one to LAN, one to Internet.

Something like pfSense firewall (loads of features, lots of plugins), or a trick hardware router.  For a nice per-user gui, an Internet Cafe type appliance might work.  For just monitoring, Cacti will give you per-user and per-application traffic.

You can associate users with MAC addresses so you don't need an authenticating proxy.

You might want to enable a squid transparent proxy though, this will save you bandwidth.

If your firewall or appliance has layer 7 or QoS capabilities you can throttle or block the torrents and prioritise the gaming apps, as well as measure the latency and view the hogs.